# How can i resolve loops issues code in ppython

Tags: python, loops

Hi everyone i'm new here, and i i'm learning python too for my university, i'm stuck on this problem, i have to create a list of week days and put the values ad miles then i have to do the total and count the cost of the petrol but i need to insert loops and tell to the program is the value is less then 0 to go back and insert the value again.
This is my problem, if someone can help me i will be happy.
thanks.

```
myDay = day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7

day1 = int(input("Enter miles for Monday:"))
day2 = int(input("Enter miles for Tuesday:"))
day3 = int(input("Enter miles for Wednesday:"))
day4 = int(input("Enter miles for Thursday:"))
day5 = int(input("Enter miles for Friday:"))
day6 = int(input("Enter miles for Saturday:"))
day7 = int(input("Enter miles for Sunday:"))

if myDay <= 0:
    print("that number is wrong, select a number superior then 0")
    myDay = int(input("Try again"))

total = day1 + day2 + day3 + day4 + day5 + day6 + day7
print("The total mileage is", total)

print("Cost of petrol", total * 1.35 / 11.2)
```

Comment: please post code in question not a picture

Comment: Store the days you get from input into a list first, then use a variable to store your total value and add up every value of that list by applying the cycles syntax (while/for).

Comment: welcome to stack,  please see this link for good question asking:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The first line itself is an error: `myDay = day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7` since `day1-7` have not been defined. Are you sure you pasted your code correctly? Maybe that line should come _after_ all your inputs. Also, since `myDay` is a tuple, you can't just compare it with `< 0` and assume Python knows what you want to do with it. That would also raise an error.

Comment: @aneroid how can i fix the problem with the list, because can not find the solution. how can i tell the program to back to the value entered < then 0 and enter again?

Answer (score 2):

By creating a function, you can simply add a while that will retry while the condition is not met.

```py
def new_day(day_name):
    day = 0
    first = True
    while day <= 0:
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            print("that number is wrong, select a number superior then 0")
        day = int(input(f"Enter miles for {day_name}:"))

    return day


day1 = new_day("Monday")
day2 = new_day("Tuesday:")
day3 = new_day("Wednesday:")
day4 = new_day("Thursday:")
day5 = new_day("Friday:")
day6 = new_day("Saturday:")
day7 = new_day("Sunday:")

total = day1 + day2 + day3 + day4 + day5 + day6 + day7
print("The total mileage is", total)

print("Cost of petrol", total * 1.35 / 11.2)
```

EDIT:
by suggestion of @aneroid using dict comprehension on a list of days simplifies the code:

```py
def new_day(day_name):
    day = 0
    first = True
    while day <= 0:
        if first:
            first = False
        else:
            print("that number is wrong, select a number superior then 0")
        day = int(input(f"Enter miles for {day_name}:"))

    return day


days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

day_miles = {day: new_day(day) for day in days}
total = sum(day_miles.values())
print("The total mileage is", total)

print("Cost of petrol", total * 1.35 / 11.2)
```

Comment: You should check the value before deciding to present the error message. As it is currently, if the first value entered is negative, then the error message doesn't appear and it just re-asks the input. And if the 2nd time the input is correct, then it would show the error message because of the first one being wrong. And then exists the loop. Or, easier, move the `input` line to _after_ the `if first... else` part.

Comment: you are right my code was wrong I corrected it!

Comment: Hey Floh i tried your code but i didn't manage my problem, i need the code to back to the value, e.g Wednesday if i insert the value -2

Comment: @Gelly I don’t understand. If you enter -2, it should ask again for the Wednesday day. Isn’t it what you want?

Comment: @Floh i just check now your correct code and is working properly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gelly Great ! Don’t hesitate to upvote and validate the answer :)

Comment: You can make this more Pythonic (idiomatic) by doing something like: `weekdays = ["Monday", "Tuesday", ..., "Sunday"]` and then `day_miles = [new_day(day) for day in weekdays]`. Then each day is prompted and added to the list. Followed by a `total = sum(day_miles)`.

Answer (score -1):

how are you doing, i am also newcomer in python learning, so i think that's the solution:

```
day1=int(input('Enter miles:'))
day2=int(input('Enter miles:'))

weekday=[day1, day2]

for i in weekday:
  if i<=0:
    print('that number is wrong, type another one:')
    i=int(input('write:'))
    weekday.append(i)

total=sum(weekday)
print(total)
print(total*1.35/11.2)
```

Comment: This will not work, you are adding at the end instead of replacing, and this retries only once, not each time the value is negative.

Comment: Yes you're right, I double-checked, I just add at the end, it's wrong.

Comment: hey lennox i tried your code but not working as i need, thanks anyway. If you find other solution let me know pls.